# HTML5 draft API and it's features

Tags: html

Why web storage API, web workers API and geolaction API are referred
as HTML5 features if they are into different working draft?

Answer (score 0):

A more technically accurate term would be [Web Appliations 1.0](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete.html) but obviously that will never become a popular term. To be precise, HTML5 is a subset of Web Applications 1.0.

"HTML5" is the easiest way to refer generically to all the modern web features that allow web application development (and no good alternative name has stuck). Some of them (like WebSockets) were at one time part the HTML5 standard and moved to a separate standard (but they are all collectively part of Web Applications 1.0)

This [table](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_various_versions_of_the_spec.3F) is useful for seeing the relationships.